# Pasar references y Bindear una function en React con parametros

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

he estado leyeno varios post por ejemplo estos docs de React *https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback*, sobre todo la parte en la que le pasas parametros a las function cuando estas handling events , y lo que no me queda claro es cuando o como sabemos cuando solamente queremos pasar una referencia hacia la funcion y cuando queremos ejecutarla pasando paramaetros a la misma, por ejemplo, en el ejemplo de los Docs , al principio lo que hace es pasar al evento onClick una referencia hacia la function que en el ejemplo esta definida, `<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Clickéame</button>` , pero luego mas adelante lo que hace es ejecutar esa function con los params que la function necesita, por ejemplo `onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)} />` , lo que no acabo de entender, por mas que leo y leo y vuelvo a leer, es cuando pasar solo una referencia hacia una function y cuando pasarle los parametros ? lo mismo ocurre con `onChange` he visto ejemplos en los cuales les pasas a `onChange`solo una referencia hacia la function que ejecuta el change y `setea` el `state` y en otros en los cuales ejectuas la function en el `onChange`: ejemplo `onChange={(e) => this.setState({state: e.target.value}}`, esto es muy confuso para mi, cualquier ayuda sera muy muy apreciada, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Buena pregunta @Nerfi.

Vamos a declarar en una clase que extiende React.Component un controlador para el evento onChange de un input de tipo texto.

```js
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (event) => {
    event.target.value será el valor del input
  }
}
```

Imagina que tienes un input de tipo texto al que pasamos la **referencia** al método, pero no lo invocamos.

```js
<input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
```

Hasta aquí todo normal, cada vez que hay un cambio en el input se **invoca** el método **handleChange** y recibimos el evento con el valor.

Ahora vamos a poner otro caso, suponemos que queremos añadir un id.

```js
<input type="text" onChange={handleChange(id)} />
```

Aquí es donde la cosa se complica porque **esto  provoca que en cada render del componente se llame al método `handleChange`** y no es el comportamiento que queremos.

Hay varias opciones para manejar estos casos, por ejemplo

```js
<input type="text" onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, id)} />
```

Bien, de esta manera la función ya no va a ser ejecutada en cada render sino que se ejecutará **únicamente cuando haya un cambio en el input** y además tendríamos que modificar `**handleChange**` para que **reciba 2 parámetros** y no uno como ahora mismo.

Otra opción sería:

```js
<input type="text" onChange={handleChange(id)} />
```

Aquí aparentemente estaríamos invocando la función en cada render, pero espera y veras.
Para este caso (un poco más avanzado) hacemos uso del curry y tendríamos que modificar el método de la siguiente manera:

```js
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  handleChange = (id) => (event) => {
    id sería el id que pasamos y
    event.target.value será el valor del input
  }
}
```

Espero que te ayude a entender un poco más como funciona.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Adolfo, vamos a ver, para ver si me he enterado de como fucniona esto y de sus diferencias, la manera mas comun de manejar eventos seria atraves de ** referencias * * hacia dicha ** function**, como por ejemplo aqui `<input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />`. Pero en el caso de necestiar parametros, lo que podriamos hacer eso, lo siguente: `<input type="text" onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, id)} />`con lo que la function nos quedaria asi: ` handleChange = (event, id) => {
    event.target.value será el valor del input, id: id
  }`, siendo este caso el mejor no ?

Comment: Efectivamente! Aunque el mejor sería el que tú decidas que mejor se adapta a ti, en tema rendimiento, ya entraríamos a hablar de otras cosas, pero tal y como lo has comentado te vale.

Comment: Vale, soy bastente nuevo y todavia no controlo esto demasiado bien, entonces, para hacer mu vida mas facil y evitar renderizar la function cada vez, podria solamente usar referencias a las function y en las funciones, usar los parametros que necesite y punto? asi si necesito pasar esa funcion como prop o algo simplemente la puedo invocar en otro componente verdad ? Muchas gracias

Comment: Así es ;), practicarlo un poco y listo.

Comment: Vale pues muchisimas gracias tio, me has ayudado un monton, hay alguna forma en la que pueda contartat contigo en caso que tenga alguna otra duda? por lo general mis dudas son bastantes estupidas pero aveces necesito hacer ese tipo de preguntas, Gracias de todas formas =)